# How do I create subsets of one list from one condition in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ, how can I split a list into different sets of list that have the same value ?

In my case, I have a list of tuple (see example below). I want to split my list by X subsets where every item2 is equal. I already found a solution, which is to do a `GroupBy` on `string` to get all possible values of `item2` into a list and then inside a `foreach`, get a new list where item2 is equal to the current `string`.

However, I feel it is not efficient and there must be a single LINQ statement that does it all. I would like to know it for the future.

The desired output should be lists of Tuples, by the amount of distinct values in the string column

```
+-------+--------+
| bool  | string |
+-------+--------+
| true  | type1  |
| false | type1  |
| true  | type2  |
| false | type1  |
| false | type2  |
+-------+--------+
```

My Code looks like this:

```
 var items2 = results.GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Item2);

            foreach (var item in items2)
            {
                var links = results.Where(tuple => tuple.Item2 == 
                            item.Key).ToList();

                // Do what I want with the links List of my Tuple
            }
```

Comment: GroupBy() should be optimal - what does your code look like?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I updated my desired output and added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            (bool, string)[] tuples =
            {
                (true,  "type1"),
                (false, "type1"),
                (true,  "type2"),
                (false, "type1"),
                (false, "type2")
            };

            var data = tuples
               .GroupBy(item => item.Item2)
               .Select(group => group.ToList())
               .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine($"Group count = {data.Count}");

            foreach (var list in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Group count = 2
(True, type1), (False, type1), (False, type1)
(True, type2), (False, type2)
```

This assumes that you wanted your output as a list of the groups (where each group is a list of `(bool, string)` tuples).

Note that you don't *have* to turn the groups into lists if you only need to access the elements via `foreach`; for example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            (bool, string)[] tuples =
            {
                (true,  "type1"),
                (false, "type1"),
                (true,  "type2"),
                (false, "type1"),
                (false, "type2")
            };

            var groups = tuples.GroupBy(item => item.Item2);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                foreach (var item in group)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item + ", ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly this, but I'm wondering what does the `.Select(group => group.ToList())` statement does ? What I did was a GroupBy like you and then in another line, a `Where()` statement `where item2 == groupbyClause.Key`

Comment: `group => group.ToList()` just takes all the items in the group and turns them into a list - otherwise it's an `IEnumerable((bool, string))` (for this example). A group is just a key (the value the items are grouped on) and an IEnumerable of all the items in that group.

Comment: @luisarcher I added another example to show how you'd access the groups' items without turning them into lists - which would of course be more efficient if you can do that.